# How to return list of list on template flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How to output list[] of list on template of flask ?

I have table[]

```
table = [[ str(i + 1)  if (i + 1) % 2 == 0 else i + 1,
                   href[i] if (i + 1) % 2 == 0 else href[i],
                   href2[i] if (i + 1) % 2 == 0 else href2[i]] for i in range(len(href))]

return render_template('index.html',table=table)
```

I want this like this

```
<table>
<tr>
{% for table in table %}
<th>{{href[1]}} ,{{href2[1]}}</th>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
```

i want this output

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>href[1] ,href2[1]</th>
<th>href[2] ,href2[2]</th>
<th>href[3] ,href2[3]</th>
...
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your table is

```
[ [ "A", "B", "C" ],   
  [ "1", "2", "3" ] ]
```

etc

So your loop should be

```
{% for row in table %}
   <th>{{row[0]}} ,{{row[1]}}</th>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is the result is like that ? 
<th>A, 1</th>
<th>B, 2</th>
<th>C, 3</th>